# Можно ли настроить gulp для подстановки обработанных ресурсов?

Tags: gulp

То есть. Например, когда мы создаем в src/index.html следующую разметку:

```
<link rel="stysheet" href="stylus/common.stylus">
```

После обработки препроцессором stylus и минимизатором получаем файл `app.min.css`.
Но в файле `built/index.html` мы получим ту же строку. Можно ли как-то настроить gulp, чтобы получить в `built/index.html`?

```
<link rel="stysheet" href="stylus/app.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вы пишите `common.stylus` в атрибут `src`? 
Gulp компилирует уже готовые файлы в папку `build`, просто пишите сразу путь к файлу стилей который лежит в `built` и все. Вы ведь проверяете уже готовую сборку.

Comment: Тогда получается, что в исходниках будут находятся ссылки на скомпилированные файлы. Ничего страшного в принципе в этом нет, но это как-то неправильно.

Comment: Странная у вас логика. Это правильно и по другому никак. Сами подумайте, зачем указывать в исходном html ссылку на стайлус? Да и браузер не понимает такое расширение, ему нужен css.

Comment: Вы говорите, что у меня странная логика, а сами говорите о том, что браузер не понимает stylus. То, что браузер не понимает stylus это очевидно, да и вообще какое это отношения имеет к моему вопросу? P.S. исходники написаны на языке препроцессора и предназначены для препроцессоров, а не для браузера.